# User Agent in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, analytics, tracking, ads

What is the default user agent if I want to add third party code (analytics or ads) in an iPhone app and how can I do to change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the user-agent in the header of your request like this:

```
NSString* userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8) Gecko/20051111 Firefox/1.5 BAVM/1.0.0";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Get current user-agent / lookup user-agents for specific browsers:
http://www.useragentstring.com/

The user-agent generally makes no difference.
Just use the default one, or better, don't worry about it.

Comment: I was wondering about changing the user agent, cause it seems that cookies are affected by user-agent (so in one app, you would have cookies from a marketing tool that are not directly readable by the app). When you look at HTTP requests sent by an app, you can see several requests for tracking apps and displaying ads when there is a custom user-agent (not the one of your app).